# Saber si un String tiene solo numeros o solo letras y si tiene numeros y letras

Tags: php

Hola quiero saber de una función en PHP que tenga solo letras y si tiene números y letras
estaba haciendo esta función pero solo identifica si son letras o números, pero no identifica si tiene letras y números al tiempo.

```
$dato = "2b";


if(ctype_punct($dato)){
    echo "tiene letras";
} else {
    echo "No tiene letras";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Con la función `is_numeric()`:

```
$dato = "2b";


if(is_numeric($dato)){
   echo "solo numeros";
} else {
   echo "numeros y letras o algun otro caracter";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tienes dos opciones (de mi parte)**

[documentación: is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-numeric.php) 
[documentación: ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit)

**Diferencias:**

`is_numeric` y `ctype_digit` hacen cosas muy diferentes.

`is_numeric` le dirá si el contenido de la variable es numérico (es decir, verdadero si es un punto flotante o un valor entero).

`ctype_digit` le dirá si una cadena no contiene más que caracteres numéricos (realizará la misma verificación que su función isNum).

el mejor enfoque es probablemente verificar si ctype_digit es verdadero ya que el ejemplo dado es un string:

**Ejemplo:**

```
$dato = "2b";

if(ctype_digit($dato)){
    echo "Solo numero";
} else {
    echo "Contiene Letras";
}
```

***Nota:** tenga en consideración que ctype_digit es mucho mas rápido que is_numeric*

POST Original: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462479/4717133)

***Siguiente nivel:*** También puedes emplear la validación ternaria (1 sola linea de código):

```
$dato = "21";

echo (ctype_digit($dato))? "solo numeros": "Contiene Letras";
```

**Aclaración de numero con exponentes:**

Según las expresiones numéricas cualquier numero con la siguiente estructura: `#e#` calificara a la variable como valor numérico, ya que la `e` en esta caso representa la exponenciación.

```
$dato = "2e8";

echo (ctype_digit($dato))? "solo numeros": "Contiene Letras";
```

output:

> solo numeros